# Factory Reset Windows through C#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to Factory Reset Windows through a C# application? Or just open up the windows process that does it for you?
I've tried to start the process like so but it didn't work:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\SystemSettingsAdminFlows.exe", "ResetPC");
```

When I try to start the 'SystemSettingsAdminFlows' process, it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Running as admin doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I love this question. My advice is thus: Try it. The aim is not the goal, it's the journey.

Comment: @ThomasWeller No, that isn't my intention. There is an application built-in with Windows 10 called 'Reset this PC' which I simply want to start. I just want to click a button, start 'Reset this PC' and close the form.

Comment: @Sentinel Thank you :). I've tried multiple things and played around with it but couldn't do it. However I will try to find a way.

Comment: Don't give up. When you know for sure, that you can or cannot, you will have mastered many new things.

Comment: @ThomasWeller My bad. I've updated the question with what happens when I try to run it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller SystemSettingsAdminFlows process doesn't start because apparently it doesn't exist.

Comment: and,... of course you have checked that it actually exists on your disk ? can you start it manually from a  `cmd` or `ps` shell window for instance?

Comment: @Pac0 Running it through cmd doesn't throw any errors but the process doesn't start. And yes, the application definitely does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to troubleshoot FileNotFound issues. Configure a filter for the executable that is affected. Look for errors that say "Path not found" or "Name not found". This may happen often, since Windows might not find the file immediately and then try everything in %PATH%. So you need to find files that have "Path not found" or "Name not found" AND NOT have "Success" later on.

The process is tedious to follow, so I wrote a tool called [ProcMon Log Analyzer](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/) that does it for you. To use it, save a Process Monitor log as XML file and use that file as input for the tool. It will tell you the names of DLLs which are missing.

Comment: Unfortunately my server is currently down, so you cannot download the tool right now. I'll see whether I have a local copy that I can make available.

Comment: @Pawel: You can get it here: https://ufile.io/zchea (until ~2018-02-10)